# Spin orbit coupling in transitional metal dichalcogenides (TMDC)

Tags: solid-state-physics, graphene, spin-orbit

I am doing studies on 2D materials, especially graphene and transitional metal dichalcogenides (TMDC). But I always have a question on the spin-orbit coupling (SOC) in TMDC: why does the spin-orbit splitting in the valence band (VB) 10~20 times larger than that in the conduction band (CB)?

In fact, I have checked several papers analyzing such difference, especially the following ones:

[Zhu, Zhiyong Y., Yingchun C. Cheng, and Udo Schwingenschlögl. "Giant spin-orbit-induced spin splitting in two-dimensional transition-metal dichalcogenide semiconductors." Physical Review B 84.15 (2011): 153402.](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.153402)

[Xiao, Di, et al. "Coupled spin and valley physics in monolayers of MoS 2 and other group-VI dichalcogenides." Physical review letters 108.19 (2012): 196802.](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.196802)

[Kormányos, Andor, et al. "Spin-orbit coupling, quantum dots, and qubits in monolayer transition metal dichalcogenides." Physical Review X 4.1 (2014): 011034.](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.4.011034)

In a nutshell, all of them say: "...because the main contribution of the CB state is made of
d<sub>z</sub><sup>2</sup> orbitals (which has out-of-plane orientation and carries no angular momentum) and thus it remains spin degenerate."

However in the spin-orbit coupling Hamiltonian, which is proportional to **L** * **S**, I can't see any contribution from the magnetic quantum number. Can someone explain why they explain it in this way?

Update 2022/12/19:
I found a helpful paper that calculates the SOC in TMD by using three-band tight-binding model:

G. B. Liu et al. “Three-band tight-binding model for monolayers of group-VIB transition metal dichalcogenides”. In: Physical Review B (2013).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the orbital $d_{z^2}$ corresponds to the magnetic quantum number $m_l=0$ describing orbital-related magnetism. When spin-orbit coupling is turned on, the magnetic quantum number becomes $m_j$ describing magnetism of the coupled spin and orbit. This number happens to also have only one value of $0$, i.e.  $m_j=0$. For a non-zero spin-orbit splitting, this quantum number should be non-zero.

See more details in [Ph.D. Thesis - Optical spectroscopy and hyloscopy of monolayers of tungsten disulphide](http://hdl.handle.net/1959.3/455711)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read the thesis that your share for more detail. Actually I also read another paper that calculates spin-orbit coupling (SOC) by using a three-band tight binding model. There I can indeed see SOC vanishes for dz^2 oribital. I was wondering if there is a "physical" picture to explain this. For example, can I say that given the 2D nature, spin of electron is perpendicular to the material (if I remember correctly). Then for dz^2 orbital, it seems like electron doesn't "rotate" and thus no SOC.

Comment: Regarding the orientation of spin, yes, it has to be perpendicular to the surface, as also discussed in the thesis. This is ultimately a result of the presence of the mirror symmetry in a monolayer. Then, since m$_j$=0, then it just means that there is no preferential orientation of the spin to be up or down and therefore both directions are equally probable, which manifests as no-to-little SOC of the conduction band.